# Connecting an Android device with a non electrical object

Tags: android, iot

I am not sure if I am asking this question on an appropriate platform on not.

I am an Android Developer. I just want to develop a simple app in which I need a signal from a non electrical object. It is a plastic clip. The app will show a message on screen when the clip is open and when the clip is closed. A diagram of the idea would be something like shown in the image. Can it be achieved using a USB cable or a simple Aux cable. Do I need any other device as an intermediate to make the communication happen between app and the clip.

I cannot use any power source like a battery cell with the plastic clip or any intermediate device.

I just need to make the communication happen between the clip and the app.

[image]

Comment: use the camera and openCV

Comment: the wire is an intermediate device

Comment: The USB port from the phone can be used as a power source, right? Would that work for you? If the answer is no, how would you imagine the communication?

Comment: @Michiel Yes, it is possible for me, in that case i will need to use a usb cable as a power source and communication medium too. Can u suggest a solution using this way??

Comment: @CommonsWare my only objective is to get a data or signal in the android device/app when the clip is open / close.